# Laravel DB Seeding not autoloading Model classes

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, composer-php

In Laravel 4.2 I've suddenly run into an issue where it won't autoload my model classes when I attempt to `php artisan db:seed`. The strange thing is that it was working fine yesterday, but now today it isn't.

I'm trying some pretty simple stuff:

**DatabaseSeeder.php**

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {

public function run()
{
    Eloquent::unguard();

    Song::truncate();

    $this->call('SongsTableSeeder');
    $this->command->info('Songs table seeded!');
}

}
```

**SongsTableSeeder.php**

```
class SongsTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run() 
    {
        $song = [
            // all my fields
        ];
        Song::create($song);

    }

}
```

When I run `php artisan db:seed` I get this error:

`Class 'Song' not found in /path/to/app/database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php`

I've tried running `composer dump-autoload` many times as well as `php artisan dump-autoload`. I've also tried running `composer update`.

If I explicitly load the class in both files like so: `use App\Models\Song;`

then my database gets seeded properly. But, this sort of defeats the point of Laravel's autoloader, right?

The `autoload` section of my `composer.json` looks like:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
```

And my `Song` model (**Song.php**) looks like:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

class Song extends \Eloquent {

protected $table = 'songs';

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you provide the `"autoload"` section of your composer.json file? there should be an `"app/models"` entry inside of the `"classmap"` property

Comment: I've added it above. It is in there.

Comment: how about looking in `/app/start/global.php` .. there should be a call to `ClassLoader::addDirectories()` with `app_path() . '/models'` inside the array parameter?

Comment: You should check the autoload_classmap.php file in app/vendor/composer. Also, I'm assuming that your Song model extends Eloquent directly.

Comment: @watcher: Yeah. `app_path().'/models'` appears in that `global.php`.

Comment: @TonyArra: Correct. I have this in `autoload_classmap.php`: `'App\\Models\\Song' => $baseDir . '/app/models/Song.php',` and in my `Song` model I have what I've added above in the original post. Like I said, this was working fine yesterday. Very strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php namespace App\Models;   class Song extends \Eloquent {
```

If you want your song model in the global namespace, then don't put it in a namespace.  Otherwise you'll have to `use App\Models\Song;` in order to load it.  Once you do that, it should work for your Seeder.  If you then need to use it inside of a different namespace, you will then need to bring it in from the global namespace with `use Song;`

Comment: np :) glad we got to the issue

Comment: I must have not had those `namespaces` in there when it was working. Live and learn. :)